# Overriding internal GPS Android for use with Navigation

Tags: android, gps, location, overriding

If I want to override the GPS position to come from another source for all applications on a device(including Google maps), an external GPS locator in this instance, would it require a change to source code?

I've seen mock locations being used but as I understand this mock data does not feed into Google Maps and so would not work?

Source code change or is there any other way of doing this?

To be fair a point in the right direction of the source code which would need changing would be nice also!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should use a custom mock provider:

```
    //Instantiate in your activity
    LocationManager lm = getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //Add a test provider
    lm.addTestProvider("myprovider", false, false, false, false, true, true, true, Criteria.POWER_HIGH, Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

    //Update the last location your provider will serve
    Location fakeLoc = ...;
    lm.setTestProviderLocation("myprovider", fakeLoc);

    //Using your custom location provider
    LocationProvider customProvider = lm.getProvider("myprovider");
```

You can see the docs for most important methods [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#setTestProviderLocation%28java.lang.String,%20android.location.Location%29).

As each application chooses which provider to use, you can't force them to use yours. Also, the client apps should have the permission `ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION` which is another thing you can't force.

But you could try to register a mock provider with the default gps provider name:

```
    lm.addTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, Criteria.POWER_HIGH, Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
```

The OS should prevent you of succeeding on this (if not, this would be a major security flaw).